# Lister CRUD add other entity column to lister

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-backpack

How can I add a column value from another entity to the lister CRUD? I have a table `company` with the fields name and address and I want a column name from the entity `customer` into the `lister`. I want a header:

company.name, company.address and customer.name

I have two models with relation methods. I can't find it here.

https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/v3.0/docs/crud-full-api

Is that possible, and how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create relationship in your Model and use `whereHas`

```
$this->crud->addClause('whereHas', 'customers', function($query) {
     $query->customers();
 });
```